# In which cases I can't use determiner after "part of" before a noun?

Tags: partitives

If I use a "part of" partitive, when can not I use determiner after "of" before noun? I can not find an example.

Comment: part of is not called a partitive in English. part of something. The of goes with what follows.

Answer (score 0):

A determiner will be needed at some point in the sentence, but not necessarily after "of".

E.G.
"The mantel is a part of Earth."

Even in this situation, you can still use a determiner after "of" though:

"The mantel is a part of the Earth."

So I don't think there is a time when you can't use one, but there are definitely times when you don't need one.

Comment: Could I say "The mantel is part of the Earth."?

Comment: the mantle, not mantel